# Configurescript for another script

Tags: bash, variables, scripting, moc

I am creating a simple bash script which opens a mediaplayer at a certain time and increases it's volume over time. Since I want to share this script later with several people I was wondering if it is possible to create another script that let's the other users change values to their liking.

I know simply opening the script via texteditor would solve the problem but since I am new to bashscripting I'd love to know if there is a way of doing this without using a texteditor

Comment: Create one file `settings.sh` with values like `WELCOME_MESSAGE="your own message"` and things like that. Then in your main script source this file `. settings.sh` and you are ready to use `$WELCOME_MESSAGE` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, i'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest way

source your config file

`. /pathto/myconfig`

then set the values in the config file that can be opened in a text editor

```
#explanation of parameter
PARAM1="...."
```